# Get user meta returns two values instead of one - Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

`SELECT count(*) FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'software_type' AND user_id = 577`

`count(*)1`

`SELECT count(*) FROM wp_users WHERE ID = 577`

`count(*)1`

Logged in and in an arbitrary template file the following code:

```
 $user_id = get_current_user_id();
 $user_meta = get_user_meta($user_id);
 var_dump($user_id, $user_meta['software_type']);
```

dumps this to screen:

`int(577) array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "Software 1" } int(577) array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "Software 1" }`

Why the duplicates of everything? Naturally I'm only expecting one.

Answer (score 0):

`get_user_meta($user_id, $key, $single)` has three argument.

Here `$single` represents the return data.
If true return value of meta data field, if false return an array. This parameter has no effect if `$key` is left blank.

You can use this to get specific key value.

```
$res = get_user_meta($user_id, 'software_type', true );

var_dump( $res );
```

Comment: I tried using the function with three variables originally and the same thing happens.

Comment: Would you please show me the content of `var_dump( $res );`

Comment: `string(10) "Software 1" string(10) "Software 1"`

Comment: are you trying those line of code inside a hook or filter ?

Comment: They're called from within the loop (template file), but make no use of hooks or filters.